# Options to bind arguments to a function in flutter

Tags: flutter, function, dart, methods

I want to bind an argument with a method. I have one method named Method1 in my application, and I want to pass Method2 as an argument to Method1. I want to bind extra arguments to Method2 while passing a Method2 to Method1. Method2 is of the type void Function(ListObject>).

In TypeScript there is an option to bind extra arguments to a function.

```
function log(...args) {
console.log(this, ...args);
}
const boundLog = log.bind("this value", 1, 2);
const boundLog2 = boundLog.bind("new this value", 3, 4);
boundLog2(5, 6);
 
 Output => // "this value", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Here's some code from what I tried.

```
Method1(
text,
Method2,
);

void Method2(List<Object> arg){ 

// My logics here....

}

void Method1(String newText, void Function(List<Object>) newMethod)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
void method2(List<Object> args) {
  print('method2');
  args.forEach((element) {
    print(element);
  });
}

void method1(String newText, void Function(List<Object>) newMethod) {
  print('method1 $newText');
  newMethod(['arg1', 'arg2']);
}

void main() {
  method1(
    'do some stuff',
    method2,
  );
}
```

or

```
void method1(
       String newText, 
       void Function(List<Object>) newMethod, 
     ) {
       print('method1 $newText');
       newMethod.call([newText]);
     }

void main() {
  method1('do some stuff',
   (args) {
    method2(args);
   },
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vladyslav, Thank you for the response. In my case, the solution did not work. I want to bind an additional argument to Method2 other than List<Object> and use it in Method2. I can't change anything in Method1 because it's from a third-party package and Method2 will be called once got a response from the server.

Comment: if you can't change anything in method1 then you can't change signature in method2 that method1 accepts as parameter. but you can try use extentions to wrap method1

Comment: Hi Vladyslav, What extensions do you are meant to wrap to Method1? Could you please provide some examples?

Comment: This is only an option for finding the right directionhttps://dart.dev/language/extension-methods